# Move Date to Monday in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a function in TSQL that will move the date to Monday if the date passed is either a Saturday or Sunday only.

For example:

- 5/6/2012 should return 5/7/2012
- 5/12/2012 should return 5/14/2012

If the date is not a Saturday or Sunday, return the input date

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Some variations of DATEADD, but I found what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will give you the Monday following if the date is a Saturday or Sunday; otherwise, it will give you the date you provided.

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME; SET @Date = GETDATE();

SELECT
    CASE (@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(dw, @Date)) % 7
        WHEN 0 THEN DATEADD(day, 2, @Date) -- Saturday
        WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(day, 1, @Date) -- Sunday
        ELSE @Date
    END AS Weekday
```

**EDIT**:  Included **Conrad Frix**'s solution to the @@DATEFIRST issue.

Comment: -1 This will break if the value of @@DATEFIRST isn't what you expect it to be

Comment: I tested this with several dates and I don't see a problem.

Comment: You can fix it by just by changing your CASE statement to  `CASE (@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(dw, datevalue)) % 7 `

Comment: @InternetEngineer did you try `SET DATEFIRST = 1` and see what happens

Comment: @ConradFrix - Included your fix.  (Needed to change my WHEN for Saturday as well with your update.)

Comment: The downvote is a bit harsh IMO; while the comment is factually accurate, @@DATEFIRST is not something that is likely to change

Comment: This should not play a role since my DateFirst is = 7. But you are correct, this will not work in other language\culture

Comment: @InternetEngineer - I've included **Conrad Frix**'s solution to the @@DATEFIRST issue in the updated answer; this should now be accurate regardless of @@DATEFIRST.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DatePart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function in T-SQL. For each date, you can extract day component, and if it's a Saturday, increment the date by two days. If it's Sunday, increment the date by one day. You can use [DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) to increment a date.

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon your [SET DATEFIRST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) options (US English default is 7, for Sunday = 1):

```
CASE
    WHEN DATEPART(weekday, @dt) = 1 -- Sunday
        THEN DATEADD(day, 1, @dt)
    WHEN DATEPART(weekday, @dt) = 7 -- Saturday
        THEN DATEADD(day, 2, @dt)
    ELSE
        @dt 
END
```

Answer (score 2):

A version that is not depending on `set datefirst`

```
select dateadd(day,
               case datediff(day, '17530101', @D) % 7
                 when 5 then 2
                 when 6 then 1
                 else 0 
               end,
               @D)
```

Same thing perhaps prettier.

```
select case datediff(day, '17530101', @D) % 7 
         when 5 then dateadd(day, 2, @D) 
         when 6 then dateadd(day, 1, @D) 
         else @D 
       end
```

The constant `17530101` is a Monday and works for `datetime`. If you are using `date` you can use `00010101` instead.

Comment: Fails when you `SET @D  = '1899-12-31'` (Which is a Sunday)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT CASE datepart(dw, @date) WHEN 7 THEN @date + 2 WHEN 1 THEN @date + 1 ELSE @date END
```

Comment: Hmm, working in 2005 now too.  Wonder why it wasn't when I was testing the first time..

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you.  Basically adds 2 days on Saturday or 1 day on Sunday to move the sample date to Monday

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
    dtSample DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('5/1/2012')
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('5/2/2012')
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('5/3/2012')
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('5/4/2012')
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('5/5/2012')
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('5/6/2012')
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('5/7/2012')
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('5/8/2012')
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('5/9/2012')
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('5/10/2012')
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('5/11/2012')
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('5/12/2012')
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('5/13/2012')
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES ('5/14/2012')

SELECT 
    dtSample
    ,CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, dtSample) = 7 
        THEN dtSample + 2
        ELSE 
            CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, dtSample) = 1
                THEN dtSample + 1
                ELSE dtSample
            END
     END AS dtConverted             
FROM @Temp
```

Results:

```
dtSample    dtConverted
2012-05-01 00:00:00.000 2012-05-01 00:00:00.000
2012-05-02 00:00:00.000 2012-05-02 00:00:00.000
2012-05-03 00:00:00.000 2012-05-03 00:00:00.000
2012-05-04 00:00:00.000 2012-05-04 00:00:00.000
2012-05-05 00:00:00.000 2012-05-07 00:00:00.000
2012-05-06 00:00:00.000 2012-05-07 00:00:00.000
2012-05-07 00:00:00.000 2012-05-07 00:00:00.000
2012-05-08 00:00:00.000 2012-05-08 00:00:00.000
2012-05-09 00:00:00.000 2012-05-09 00:00:00.000
2012-05-10 00:00:00.000 2012-05-10 00:00:00.000
2012-05-11 00:00:00.000 2012-05-11 00:00:00.000
2012-05-12 00:00:00.000 2012-05-14 00:00:00.000
2012-05-13 00:00:00.000 2012-05-14 00:00:00.000
2012-05-14 00:00:00.000 2012-05-14 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) and [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

```
select  date
,       CASE DATEPART(weekday, date)            
            WHEN 6 THEN DATEADD(day, 2, date) -- Saturday
            WHEN 7 THEN DATEADD(day, 1, date) -- Sunday
            ELSE date 
        END AS NewDate
from @dates
order by date
```

Sample data:

```
declare @dates table(date datetime);
insert into @dates values('20120401');
insert into @dates values('20120402');
insert into @dates values('20120403');
insert into @dates values('20120404');
insert into @dates values('20120405');
insert into @dates values('20120406');
insert into @dates values('20120407');
insert into @dates values('20120408');
insert into @dates values('20120409');
insert into @dates values('20120410');
```

Result:

```
date                    NewDate
2012-04-01 00:00:00.000 2012-04-02 00:00:00.000
2012-04-02 00:00:00.000 2012-04-02 00:00:00.000
2012-04-03 00:00:00.000 2012-04-03 00:00:00.000
2012-04-04 00:00:00.000 2012-04-04 00:00:00.000
2012-04-05 00:00:00.000 2012-04-05 00:00:00.000
2012-04-06 00:00:00.000 2012-04-06 00:00:00.000
2012-04-07 00:00:00.000 2012-04-09 00:00:00.000
2012-04-08 00:00:00.000 2012-04-09 00:00:00.000
2012-04-09 00:00:00.000 2012-04-09 00:00:00.000
2012-04-10 00:00:00.000 2012-04-10 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Why `DATEPART - 1`?  Why not just `DATEPART`?

Comment: @zimdanen: Would make no difference here. I've taken the code from a SP that checks for weekdays. I've used the modulo(`% 7`) there, i think that was the reason for -1. Will edit it.

Answer (score -1):

I extended the solution provided by zimdanen on 8th May as when the start date was a friday it failed .

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME

BEGIN

SET @FromDate='04/07/2014'

SELECT
     @FromDate as [StartDate]
   , CASE (@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(dw, (DATEADD(DD,3,@FromDate)))) % 7
        WHEN 0 THEN DATEADD(day, 2, (DATEADD(DD,3,@FromDate))) -- Saturday
        WHEN 1 THEN 
                    CASE    
                        WHEN DATEPART(dw,@FromDate)=5 Then DATEADD(DD,5,@FromDate) -- Thursday
                        ELSE DATEADD(day, 1, (DATEADD(DD,3,@FromDate))) -- Sunday  
                    END                       

        ELSE 
                    CASE    
                        WHEN DATEPART(dw,@FromDate)=6 Then DATEADD(DD,5,@FromDate) -- Friday
                        ELSE DATEADD(DD,3,@FromDate)
                    END 

    END AS Weekday



END
```